# Grafana Loki total number of a specific log message

Tags: logging, monitoring, grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I am using Grafana Loki and I need to calculate the total number of a certain log message for a specific time interval. For example, I need the total number of log message "some-text" in the period from 12:00:00 to 14:00:00. I just found the following way to count the occurrences of the last minute, something this: `count_over_time({container="some-containter"} |= "some-text")[1m]`, but i did not found any way to query a specific interval.

I would be very happy if this is possible and someone could help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using [Grafana Explore](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/explore/) to query your logs you can do an `instant` query and use the time range and [global variables](https://%20https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/).

So you can select the time range as seen in the screenshot below and your query would become
`count_over_time({container="some-container"} |= "some-text"[$__range])`

You can check my example in the [Grafana Playground.](https://play.grafana.org/explore?orgId=1&left=%7B%22datasource%22:%22Loki%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22,%22expr%22:%22count_over_time(%7Bhttp_method%3D%5C%22POST%5C%22%7D%20%7C%3D%20%5C%22200%5C%22%5B$__range%5D)%22,%22queryType%22:%22instant%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%221654300800000%22,%22to%22:%221654308000000%22%7D%7D)
[image]

Comment: example appears to have no data now